# A residue formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Does anybody know of a succint way to compute the residue of $f(z)=z^m/(1-e^{-z})^{n+1}$ at $z=0$? I am only interested in the nontrivial case $m<n$.
Induction seems complicated/inefficient, so I am looking for a "trick", perhaps with Lagrange inversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taylor series for denominator and then divide them to obtain the residue. The process is like division of polynomials. Of course you should be aware whether $m\le n$ or $m\ge n$.

Comment: this is not efficient.

Comment: @Rüdiger Its more efficient than induction.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that (use L'Hospital)

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^m}{(1-e^{-z})^n}=0\ \forall\ m>n$$

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^m}{(1-e^{-z})^n}=1\ \forall\ m=n$$

and thus the residue is $0$ in these cases.

Whenever $m<n$, I think you would have to use a series method with long division and such.

Comment: thats not true. the residue is ${n+m \choose m}$

Comment: @Rüdiger how do you know this?  From what I understand, if the limit to the point, taken from all directions in the complex plane, exists and is finite, then the residue is $0$.

Comment: wolfram alpha. ..

Comment: @Rüdiger I can't put it in.  Perhaps you could put the link from which you got this?

Comment: please consider deleting this answer, because it is dead wrong. just consider the special case $m=n=1$. the function is analytic, hence the residue is $0$.

Comment: @Rüdiger What do you mean this is wrong?  for $m=n=1$, I explicitly say the residue is $0$, and you only agree?  Did you not try reading my answer?

Comment: for $m=n$ you say it is 1... omg

Comment: @Rüdiger I say for $m=n$, the limit is $1$.  Thus, the residue is $0$, as mentioned, directly below.

Comment: actually when i think about it you are only addressing the trivial part of the question. If $m$ is at most $n$, then the function is obviously analytic since $z/(1-e^{-z})$ is analytic. clearly i am interested in the nontrivial case.

Comment: @Rüdiger But do you understand my answer now?

Comment: yeah, I didn't even think of the $m>n$ case, though.